# Safari 8.0 Not Rendering/Recognizing SVG files

Tags: css, django, html, svg, safari

So, I've looked it up, and Safari 8 is supposed to support SVG files.  However, when I go to my page (currently just running locally), it doesn't render any of them.  Google Chrome works fine, but for some reason, Safari 8.0 does not.  Is there a workaround that will enable Safari 8.0 to render my SVGs?  Here is the HTMl where they are used (it's a django template):

```
<div id="head">
    <a href="/"><img id="home" src="{% static 'email_registration/images/1_full_logo.svg' %}"></a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><img id="fb" src="{% static 'email_registration/images/2_facebook_icon.svg' %}"></a>
    <a href="http://www.instagram.com"><img id="inst" src="{% static 'email_registration/images/3_instagram_icon.svg' %}"></a>
    <a href="https://www.twitter.com"><img id="twtr" src="{% static 'email_registration/images/4_twitter_icon.svg' %}"></a>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com"><img id="yt" src="{% static 'email_registration/images/5_youtube_icon.svg' %}"></a>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.  Let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check is whether your webserver is serving the SVG files with the correct MIME type (Content-Type).  For SVG files it should be `image/svg+xml`.  The easiest way to find out is by using the 'Net' tab of your browsers dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

just had this issue myself and after looking at the source I realised that Adobe extract had converted the vector to an embedded png within the svg file. Not saying that's the solution to your problem but might be worth check.